# CRON notation for intervals that exceed a month

Tags: c#, .net, cron

I'm trying to store recurrences using CRON, but I've ran into a problem.
When I want to store a recurrence for say every 6 weeks, it won't work as the CRON notation resets every month as I understand it.

Are there any workarounds/fixes to this? I can't imagine I'm the only one with this problem, but haven't been able to find a fix to this as of now.

PS:
The application I want to use this for is built in C# .NET, so it would have to be implementable there.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like Quartz.net has an open feature request for exactly this functionality: https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/314  Does it need to be a cron, or could you use something like Windows Task Scheduler as an alternative?

Comment: Well it's mostly about the format. Cron seems to cover most of the usecases we have. Only problem is the intervals being limited to within a month. That's where we hit the snag.